# I want to Split by Attribute to run a function multiple times, but 'Id' is all 0?

Tags: arcpy, split-by-attribute

[image: Result of current code, ideally the 'BASIN' would be split to separate the drainage area for each point]

I want to run my function over each feature in a point shapefile layer, but splitting by attribute returns the same number of points, because the Id field is all 0.

Is there a way, using ArcPy syntax, to add unique values to the Id field, or an entirely new field of unique values?

Or, a way to split by the FID attribute, which is always unique values?

```
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    #DEFINE PARAMETERS & zLimit
    env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)     #type is folder
    inSurfaceRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)   #type is Raster Layer
    CROSSINGS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)         #type is Table View
    EXTENT = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)            #type is double
    PARCEL = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)            #type is Table View
    zLimit = 3.2808
    #CHECK OUT REQUIRED EXTENSION
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    #CLIPPING RASTER LAYER TO SMALLER AREA
    AOI = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(PARCEL,'AOI',10000)
    USR = ExtractByMask(inSurfaceRaster,AOI)
    #GENERATING REQUIRED RASTER LAYERS
    outFill = Fill(USR,zLimit)
    outFlowDir = FlowDirection(outFill)
    outFlowAcc = FlowAccumulation(outFlowDir)
    outSnapPoint = SnapPourPoint(CROSSINGS, outFlowAcc, EXTENT)
    #DELINEATION OF WATERSHEDS
    watersheds = Watershed(outFlowDir,outSnapPoint,"VALUE")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(watersheds,"BASINS")
    arcpy.AddMessage("BASINS"+CROSSINGS)
    #DELETE EXCESS SHAPEFILES
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFill)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFlowDir)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFlowAcc)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outSnapPoint)
    arcpy.Delete_management(watersheds)
    arcpy.Delete_management(AOI)
    arcpy.Delete_management(USR)
```

The above code draws a drainage basin for the 'CROSSINGS' input, my issue is that only one basin is drawn, when the idea is to have one for each point feature in 'CROSSINGS'.

If I could split 'CROSSINGS' I would then run the function over each new point.

Comment: Create a new ID field then calculate into that field FID + 1.

Answer (score 1):

To "fetch" one point at a time you can use da.SearchCursor to return each objectid then create a feature layer for each row:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput=True

shapefile = r'C:\folder\shapefile.shp'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile,'OID@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        sql= """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=shapefile, field=arcpy.Describe(shapefile).OIDFieldName), row[0])
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=shapefile, out_layer='pointlyr', where_clause=sql)
        #Do something for each point (named 'pointlyr')
```