# for loop did not generate a 'BASIN' for each 'CROSSING'

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

My code is intended to delineate watersheds from a specified "CROSSING". The purpose is to obtain the total drainage area for a point on a stream/river labeled "CROSSING". My issue is that only one "BASIN" shapefile is generated, containing all "CROSSING" points, at the location furthest downstream.

How can I alter my code to have individual "BASIN" polygons drawn, starting from the "CROSSING" point at the highest elevation?

The image is of the generated shapefile from my current code.[image]

```
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    #DEFINE PARAMETERS & zLimit
    env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)     #type is folder
    inSurfaceRasters = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  #type is Raster Layer, multiple
    CROSSINGS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)         #type is Table View
    EXTENT = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)            #type is double
    PARCEL = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)            #type is Table View
    zLimit = 3.2808
    #CHECK OUT REQUIRED EXTENSION
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    #CLIPPING RASTER LAYER TO SMALLER AREA
    inSurfaceRaster = arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(inSurfaceRasters)
    AOI = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(PARCEL,'AOI',10000)
    USR = ExtractByMask(inSurfaceRaster,AOI)
    #GENERATING REQUIRED RASTER LAYERS
    outFill = Fill(USR,zLimit)
    outFlowDir = FlowDirection(outFill)
    outFlowAcc = FlowAccumulation(outFlowDir)
    arcpy.AddXY_management(CROSSINGS)
    #DELINEATION OF WATERSHEDS 
    #---------------------------------------------------------- begin loop
    fc = CROSSINGS
    field = "POINT_X"
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    for field in cursor:
        outSnapPoint = SnapPourPoint(fc, outFlowAcc, EXTENT)
        watersheds = Watershed(outFlowDir,outSnapPoint,"VALUE")
        arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(watersheds,"BASINS")
        #DELETE EXCESS SHAPEFILES
        arcpy.Delete_management(outSnapPoint)
        arcpy.Delete_management(watersheds)
    #---------------------------------------------------------- end loop
    #DELETE EXCESS SHAPEFILES
    arcpy.Delete_management(AOI)
    arcpy.Delete_management(USR)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFill)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFlowDir)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFlowAcc)
    #LET USER KNOW LAYER IS READY
    print "Layer(s) is(are) ready to be added from "+env.workspace
```

Comment: The problem is with your cursor. You iterate over ROWS not fields. So you are feeding an entire featureclass into snapppourpoint not an individual point. You need to fix your loop and feed a selection of one point into snapppourpoint on each loop of your cursor.

Comment: @BERA answers this in your other question, pay attention to his code. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379789/i-want-to-split-by-attribute-to-run-a-function-multiple-times-but-id-is-all-0